# Adding a second overload as an object is giving two errors

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create an overload function, one which takes two arguments, and one which takes one argument as an object. They are then used like this:

```js
// As two parameters
obj.set('a', '123');
obj.set('b', 'efg');

// As a single object parameter
obj.set({ a: '123', b: 'efg' });
```

I am then declaring the overloads as follows:

```js
export type Fields<T extends BaseModel> = { [K in keyof T['fields']]: T['fields'][K] | typeof BaseModel };

export abstract class BaseModel {
  abstract fields: Fields<any>;

  // This overload works
  set<K extends keyof Fields<this>>(field: K, value: Fields<this>[K]): this;
  
  // This overload throws an error
  set<K extends keyof Fields<this>>(fields: { [key: keyof Fields<this>]: Fields<this>[K] }): this;
}
```

My single parameter overveload (as an object) is then showing this error:

> A 'this' type is available only in a non-static member of a class or interface.

Comment: The error is telling you that `K` can't be used in an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) and that you should use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) instead as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/w8B59m). Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I just solved the `K` error, but I am still getting the error about `this`

Comment: I don't get it, why are you not making [the change I put in this here playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w8B59m)?  You're making it worse by trying to use index signatures (`{[k: KKK]: VVV}`); index signatures cannot be used with arbitrary key types; you need to use mapped types (`{[P in KKK]: VVV}`) instead.

Comment: Ahhh, sorry I missed that link, that fixes the issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) and [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) look similar and can have somewhat similar effects, but they have different rules and different effects.

---

An index signature can be a part of any object type alongside other properties and signatures, and has a syntax like

```
type IndexSig = { [dummyKeyIdentifier: KeyType]: ValueType }
```

where `dummyKeyIdentifier` is a *dummy* key identifier because it is only for documentation purposes and is unobservable to the type system.  There are fairly strict rules on what `KeyType` is allowed to be; pretty much only `string`, `number`, `symbol`, ["pattern" template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#symbol-and-template-string-pattern-index-signatures), and [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of these.  You cannot use a string/number [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) like `"a"` or `3` and you cannot use a [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) like `K` in your example code, or any type involving [the polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) which behaves like an implicit generic type parameter.

Hence the errors in your code.

---

A mapped type on the other hand is a standalone type (no other properties or signatures can exist alongside it inside the curly braces), and has a syntax like

```
type MappedType = { [K in KeyType]: ValueType<K> }
```

where `K` is a *generic type parameter* that iterates over union members of `KeyType` and is in scope for the property type.  So while in an index signature the `dummyKeyIdentifier` cannot be mentioned again, you can use the `K` in a mapped type to do different things for every key in `KeyType`.

And here, the rules for `KeyType` are quite lax; any propertylike type will work.  You can still use `string`, `number`, `symbol`, and pattern template literals (although these end up being transformed into an equivalent index signature), but you can also use literal types and generic types and unions of these.

---

You can recognize the difference between them because an index signature has a colon (`:`) inside the square brackets while a mapped type has the `in` keyword.

Often the compiler will notice that you are using an index signature in a prohibited manner and suggest that you use a mapped type instead.  Sometimes the compiler doesn't realize that a mapped type will help, but that's still the underlying problem.

In your case, if you change the index signature to a mapped type:

```
declare abstract class BaseModel {
  abstract fields: Fields<any>;
  set<K extends keyof Fields<this>>(field: K, value: Fields<this>[K]): this;
  
  set<K extends keyof Fields<this>>(
    fields: { [P in keyof Fields<this>]: Fields<this>[K] } // okay
  ): this; 
}
```

things start working.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkgC4CeMyA0hKQCrnIC8SUxATgJbADmA3ISQZIAapgCuEehQA8lJBAAexCMAAmUJAAU2Aewpsy1Ukmba9EA6SMA+E0kr8i8HcFZIExMZiMBJVSuIOADMOCzsAIhAAI3hw-gEyCiQfNUUAZQ5uO1wkAG1VMTAwKxo-AODQtgAuexopCABdGtEMCXqkAF98BKEAWRAYClV25hzcuS5augYmkXFJBllbLoEAelWSAAsODR2kUghid2AdYk2ws64sqLEjnyQAdxcAciPIYECXJA4jybPkUBQB4WHpJADCOjAMFuEFURmyeQ8Xgwvn8HwqFlmLTaQhWK0UMB0BkESQAYqEMOppLR5EoVOokAAhEBQCC9HT+DC2UZ5CbAJAAaxoOiCSFouWeIQglKgzwas3Fkop6jl4waSAAPiSICKmSy2RzpZ14v54BgQGxkNFWGwPEgzSyNMzWezOXgBNb2HapTKauTpVSQMBSNZHCxDrJaco1BohaRdf6ZdJLlBrNYABQ+1Q1SgAGiQADd5n7lVBk9tU2qAJQ1FPxIis4iRxTRhlxhOl8s7NPpgRELNQGpjTTffnt0WJqkp6yzSdl6dqzoCGtbHa8JDrJA6AUgUj4DpAA)

Comment: In my case, `Fields<this>[K]` should be `Fields<this>[P]`. But otherwise this works.